# Allowing local URL in Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment

Tags: antixsslibrary

Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment seems to strip all `<a href="">link</a>` into `<a>link</a>`

Is there anyway to preserve local URL, e.g. `<a href="/Product/1">` when passing it into Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment?

Note: I'm using AntiXSS 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AntiXSS library has been [broken](http://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/) for a few months now. There's no way around this problem, unfortunately. Either you rollback to a previous version, or search for something else to use.

Comment: Looks like MS broke the library after IBM found a loophole in it. What's the alternative that's secure, but doesn't strip HTML the way AntiXSS library does?